# opa : paypal and IPN

Tags: forms, post, paypal, opa

I'd like to use paypal on my opa website. To validate a paiement, paypal propose the IPN mechainsm that send hidden POST form data to a pre defined page.

How can I get those POST value using opa ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you can use [HttpRequest.get_body()](http://doc.opalang.org/value/stdlib.core.web.request/HttpRequest/get_body) or [HttpRequest.get_form_data()](http://doc.opalang.org/value/stdlib.core.web.request/HttpRequest/get_form_data)